# linear independence of functions

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to prove that the set $\left\lbrace\frac{1}{n+x}\right\rbrace_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is linear independant in the Vector space of functions from $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ $\to$ $\mathbb{R}$.
So starting with the linear combination $\lambda_1\frac{1}{1+x} +\cdots +\lambda_{k+1}\frac{1}{k+1+x}$
,the idea was to convert it to a common denominator. Thus the polynomial in the counter is of degree k, having a maximum of k roots. This implies that the polynomial in the counter is the zero polynomial.

My problem so far is, that the only information i have about the system of equations is the first one  $\lambda_1+\cdots +\lambda_{k+1}=0$.
Does anyone know how to show that all lambdas are zero?

Comment: The step "$x = i$" in Lucas' answer below gives you a general recipe in proving linear independence of a set of functions. Basically, equality of functions means that at *each* $x$, equality holds as numbers. So, if one can substitute values of $x$ which are well-chosen, one forces a set of equations which imply $\lambda_i = 0$ for all $i$. Lucas' choice of $x$ ensured that very few $\lambda_i$ (in fact only one) was left behind.

Comment: If you add the fractions by getting a common denominator, the numerator will be a polynomial of degree $\le k$ and thus has at most $k$ roots, in which case plugging in anything else will result in something nonzero.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the sum needs to be the zero constant function. So:
$$ \lambda_1 \frac{1}{1+x}+\cdots + \lambda_n \frac{1}{n+x} = 0 \Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i\prod_{j\neq i}(j+x) = 0 $$

Taking $x = -i$, we have
$$  \lambda_i\prod_{j\neq i}(j-i) = 0 \Rightarrow \lambda_i = 0  $$
since $\prod_{j\neq i}(j-i) \neq 0$.

Comment: Note $x=-i$ is not in the original domain of the functions (nor can the original functions' domain be extended to include it). So there are some technical arguments under the hood.

Comment: Well noticed! But since it is a polynomial function it is fully defined by a finite number of points and therefore we have an unique extension of the polynomial to the real line. That extension must be zero, so, the original function must be zero.

Answer (score 1):

The linear independence can be investigated through the Wronskian
$$
W_n(x)=\begin{vmatrix}
+\frac{1}{1+x}     & +\frac{1}{2+x}     & \ldots & +\frac{1}{n+x}     \\
-\frac{1}{(1+x)^2} & -\frac{1}{(2+x)^2} & \ldots & -\frac{1}{(n+x)^2} \\
\ldots             & \ldots             & \ldots & \ldots             \\
\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(1+x)^n} & \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2+x)^n} & \ldots & \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+x)^n}
\end{vmatrix}
$$
The calculation of the Wronskian seems to be (by various tries with Wolfram Mathematica)
$$
W_n(x)=\frac{a_n}{(1+x)^n(2+x)^n\cdot\ldots\cdot(n+x)^n}
$$
where $a_n$ is the [OIES Sequence A055209](https://oeis.org/A055209), so it is different from zero and the functions are then independent.

I leave to someone clever than me the proof that the Wronskian is effectively given by the previous expression.